# Altering data types within a table using SQL command ALTER

Tags: sql, netbeans, sqlcommand, alter

I have researched how to alter table data types and I understand how to do it but I cannot get it to work. I am trying to update my table Person within APP using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE APP.PERSON ALTER uName varchar;
```

What I have tried so far:

- using Modify but realised that, after I received errors, this should indeed be ALTER.
- changing uName to UNAME.
- changing it to a data type of varchar2.
- adding in the size of the data type '(20)' and 'NOT NULL' at the end.

Where am I going wrong? I am using Netbeans 7.3 Beta 2 running on Mac OS X, this is all being done within the SQL Commands section of Netbeans, using Java-DB as my database if any of that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385020/how-to-alter-a-column-datatype-for-derby-database) on SO. You basically need to create new column with desired datatype and delete the old one. However, if you take a look into [Apache Derby doc](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html), there is a `SET DATA TYPE` command, so try something like

```
ALTER TABLE APP.PERSON ALTER UNAME SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(30)
```

**EDIT**

If code above doesn't work, then you just have to recreate the column as I suggested before.

```
ALTER TABLE APP.PERSON ADD COLUMN UNAME_NEW VARCHAR(30);
UPDATE APP.PERSON SET UNAME_NEW = UNAME;
ALTER TABLE APP.PERSON DROP COLUMN UNAME;
RENAME COLUMN APP.PERSON.UNAME_NEW TO UNAME;
```

Comment: This seems to be the command I need to use but I can't get it working, using @Joachim's response I receive this error - "Error code -1, SQL state 42Z15: Invalid type specified for column 'UNAME'. The type of a column may not be changed."

Comment: Same error - "Error code -1, SQL state 42Z15: Invalid type specified for column 'UNAME'. The type of a column may not be changed." ... that's with and without an ending semi-colon.

Comment: I don't have a running Derby to test it, so you can just fall back to original solution.

Comment: OK, thanks, one last question if I may. I understand you don't have a running Derby to test this but you may know, how do I put a column in a specific position so I can replace it's old position?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know this one. Quick look to documentation didn't tell me anything about this:(

Answer (score 1):

Most databases require specific permissions to use DDL (Data Definition Language) commands like `ALTER TABLE`.  Very often, the DB credentials used in an application tier do not have DDL permissions in the database.

Verify that the connection you are using has permission to run `ALTER TABLE`.  If indeed it does, post the specific code you are using and any specific error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have JavaDB to test on, but according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html#rrefsqlj81859__rrefsqlj37860) it should be;

```
ALTER TABLE APP.PERSON ALTER uName SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(20)
```

Comment: Thanks, I literally just tried this and came back to post my results then saw your post. I am receiving this error - "Error code -1, SQL state 42Z15: Invalid type specified for column 'UNAME'. The type of a column may not be changed."

Comment: @JohnVasiliou Which version of JavaDB are you running?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check? It's an embeddedDriver if that helps? It was shipped with Java 6 I believe.

Comment: @JohnVasiliou I suspect it's too old to have the `SET DATA TYPE` command, in which case @petr's solution of recreating the column is your only option.