# How to change datatype of the column in derby database?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, derby

Iam trying to change the datatype of the column from integer(9) to Numeric(14,3).
but not able to change

i tried below query

```
alter table TableName alter ColumnName NUMERIC (14,3);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to alter a column datatype for derby database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385020/how-to-alter-a-column-datatype-for-derby-database)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Andrej : that is for decimal to decimal, which is not useful to me.

Comment: @Boneist iam getting syntax error:
Encountered "Numeric" at line 1,Column 50

Comment: Rohit, that question describes the way to alter the datatype - looks like you'll only be able to do it by creating a new column, copying the data over, dropping the old column and then renaming the new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope below one will help.

ALTER TABLE Table_Name ALTER COLUMN Column_Name SET DATA TYPE NUMERIC(14,3);

Comment: Helped me to change the size of the column. but when trying to change the type, again getting syntax error like numeric is not possible type to change.
can you help me on this